# Adding button at the bottom of screen after listview

Tags: android

I am trying to add "Submit" button at the bottom center of screen below listview but no luck. Any idea? I have also added button code in it. I believe somewhere the fill_parent is covering up the whole screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#f4f4f4">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:text="Please select the programs/episodes you watched last week for which you will submit response"
        android:textColor="#000"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:background="#f4f4f4">

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/android:list"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_New"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:width="170dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show us what it looks like right now and what it should look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code in layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f4f4f4"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:text="Please select the programs/episodes you watched last week for which you will submit response"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="17dp" />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_New"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: It works, but if you could explain what you changed and why, that would be nice

Comment: android:layout_weight="1" in expandablelistview tag

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving the ExpandableListView a height of `match_parent`, give it a weight of 1 and a height of 0dp, this will make it so that all other elements will be shown, and the ExpandableListView takes up the remaining space

```
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use RelativeLayout and for button set the

`android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

Set the list view to be `android:layout_above="<YOUR BUTTON ID>"`